# Python library for detecting an LED flash

Tags: python, computer-vision

Is there a python library or API that can use a camera to detect LED lights at know locations? The lights will be different colors.

I am interested in making an automated production test for a PCB. My board has many LEDs, and a test command makes the board turn LEDs on when some features work correctly. People may miss one of the many lights. I specify python because its the only high level language I am familiar with. Most of my embedded work is in C, and C is tricky to work with at higher levels.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite possible to solve this. As @John Percival Hackworth said, opencv is a good choice to solve this. I can give you some pointers on how to go about it.

- Take a picture of the board with LEDs, since you know the colors of LEDs, use that knowledge to filter the colors. For which I have given a code snippet.
- After filtering the colors, You can use houghcircles/blobs to locate the LEDs
- Presence of the blob means that LED is on. You can then make decisions based on this knowledge.

Opencv has python bindings, so you can program this with python.

Snippet to do color filtering.

```
import cv2 as cv2
import numpy as np

fn = 'image_or_videoframe'
# OpenCV reads image with BGR format
img = cv2.imread(fn)
# Convert to HSV format
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Choose the values based on the color on the point/mark
lower_red = np.array([0, 50, 50])
upper_red = np.array([10, 255, 255])
mask = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower_red, upper_red)

# Bitwise-AND mask and original image
masked_red = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)
```

in this case, the red is filtered in the image and `masked_red` would contain only the red pixels in the image. You can change `lower_red` and `upper_red` to different values depending on the color you want to filter.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

[OpenCV](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python%20'OpenCV') is a possible choice that would let you segue to another language later if needed.